# Photo in pdf CV

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, jobs

Right now the .pdf is text-only. In some countries CVs with applicant photo are preferred.
Please make it possible to add photo to the .pdf version of CV.

Comment: this is what is needed to take StackOverflow CV/story seriously, from a job applying point of view

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow has [discontinued](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415293) Stack Overflow Jobs and Developer Story on March 31, 2022.

Comment: Ohhh, really? That is sad....

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a bad idea. I think the best way for us to implement this would be to just include the gravatar for your profile (the one that's optionally displayed on your online profile page) in the exported PDF.

We'll go over it on Monday and see if this is a viable option.

Comment: Problem: some avatars are just not fit for CVs, people might want a different photo there.

Comment: The Gravatar that is displayed on your profile is whichever one is linked to the email address on your profile. The short-term solution would be to just make that a toggle-able section when exporting the PDF. Allowing arbitrary uploads is something that we'll have to investigate and make sure we approach in the right way.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I've meant the gravatar. There's a choice of which profile sections to include into pdf - that would work for the image nicely.

Comment: @rossipedia this answer was in 2014, when is a photo added to the .pdf CV? In my opinion this is very important, and as an European, this would make my 'dealing with CV' much faster, since all the companies want a photo in the CV. It would make me start using StackOverflow CV/story much seriously. Can you please update what is the status of this suggestion?

Comment: Well, to be honest I haven't worked at Stack Overflow since 2018, so I'm not sure how much help I can be.

Comment: can someone at StackOverflow respond to my comment above since rossipedia no longer work at the StackOverflow company?